# Orcad PCB editor warning (Spmhdb-213)

Tags: pcb-design

I am new to Orcad. I made some changes in capture and when I am trying to generate netlist using old board as input, netlist file is generated successfully but I am not seeing changes in board on PCB editor.

I get warning

> W-(Spmhdb-213): DRC set to "out of date". The current product
>   selection supports a different DRC capability than what is saved on
>   the design.

Answer (score 1):

That means someone created that old board with a fancier, more expensive license than you currently have.  Orcad PCB and Allegro come in different tiers with different options. So for example I have options like "advanced miniaturization" to help with stacking laser micro-vias. We also have several other productivity options. If you open one of our files on someone else's machine with just a regular license, then Orcad will warn you about it.

In your case I'm "guessing" the board was done in a tool with maybe some high-speed routing rules option, or other DRC constraints. You have a lower level tool and it cannot use those constraints but it knows they're there. So I think it's warning you like, hey the last guy set some constraints on this board and I can't check them... so you might easily break a bunch of things without getting any warnings.

Comment: That old board was created by me itself on the same version software and same pc!